# ${\scr{B}}(A, Y) \cong {\scr{B} }(X, Y) $ (isometically Isomorphic)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

$X ,Y $ be two normed space and $Y$ is a Banach space.

Consider, $A\subset X$ dense linear subspace.

$\begin{align} &{{\scr{B}}(X, Y)=\{T\in {\scr{L}}(X,Y) :\forall x\in X(\exists M>0 (\|Tx\|\le M\|x\|))\}}\end{align}$

> Claim : ${\scr{B}}(A, Y) \cong    {\scr{B} }(X, Y) $ (isometically Isomorphic)

> It is enough to prove every linear map $T :A\to X $ has a unique
> continuous linear extension $\hat{T}:X\to Y$.

Let, $T:A\to Y $ a continuous linear map.

As $A\subset X $ dense .

$\forall x\in X , \exists (a_n) _{n\in \Bbb{N}}\subset A $ such that $(a_n) \to x$

Then, $(a_n) $is a cauchy sequence in $A$.

$\begin{align}\|Ta_n-Ta_m\|&=\|T(a_n-a_m) \|\\&\le \|T\|_{A\to Y} \|a_n-a_m\|\\&\to 0 \text { as } m, n\to \infty \end{align}$

Hence, $(Ta_n) \subset Y$ is cauchy and by completeness of $Y$ , $\lim_{n\to {\infty}} Ta_n =y\in Y $

Define, $\hat{T}(x) =y $ , $\space \forall x\in X$

Claim :

1. $\hat {T}$ is well-defined.
2. $\hat{T}|_{A} =T$
3. $T\in {\scr{B}}(X, Y) $
4. $\|T\|=\|\hat{T}\|_{A}$
5. $\hat{T}$ is unique extension.

$1,2,3, 4,5$ all are fine for me. I able to prove all of them.

Define, $\phi(T) =\hat{T} ,\space \space T\in {\scr{B}}(A,Y)$

Claim:

1. $\phi$ is well-defined.
2. $\phi $ is linear.
3. $\|\phi(T)\| =\|T\|$

I can prove all of three.

Hence, my original calim that ${\scr{B}}(A, Y) \cong    {\scr{B} }(X, Y) $ (isometically Isomorphic) is ture.

Please verify, add alternative solutions and correct me if there is any mistake. Thanks....

Edit : I forgot to mention that $\phi$ must be a bijective map. Thanks @Misha Lavrov for pointing out this mistake.

Comment: When you say "Suppose $\phi(T) = \hat T$ for $T \in \mathscr B(A,Y)$ is a linear norm preserving map, i.e. $\|T\|_{A\to Y}=\|T\|_{X\to Y}$" you are (1) assuming something you have to prove (2) talking about a concept $\hat T$ you haven't defined yet.

Comment: Also, you don't prove that $\phi$ is a bijection, which is part of the definition of an isomorphism.